# Ember application only shows blank page on errors, cannot render 'error' action

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to implement error handling for my Ember application, especially when the API endpoints are down.

I tried to render an error template (`error.hbs`) using the  `error()` action inside my `application` route. The rendering will result into internal error (`Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`, [see line in Ember](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/b216f384e1b0e1caa3e1103818272f76777679fa/packages/ember-routing/lib/system/route.js#L1952).

To render an error page the idea was to use the following action:

```
    error() {
        this.render('error', {
            into: 'application' // does not seem to exist
        });
    }
```

How can I force Ember to at least render something?

I use Ember 2.7.0

Comment: are you getting error in application route model hook ?..you can try below `error(error, transition) {
      if (error) {
        return this.transitionTo('error-page');
      }
    }`

Comment: @kumkanillam transitioning to another page (that does not use the backend) will also result in an `undefined` error, but another place inside Ember. Same problem basically.

Answer (score 2):

Reason for `Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`, I guess your application.hbs itself is not rendered due to error in any of the application route model hook (beforeModel,model,afterModel). you can't render `error.hbs` into application if its not redered.

so remove `error` actions from application route and define application-error.hbs template file which will be rendered automatically

[Ember-twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/55f3a834e81690005482c2ad68050b3c?openFiles=routes.application.js%2C)

Comment: didn't know about `application-error.hbs` (thanks!). The errors do not appear in the application hooks, but in nested routes. I will probably mark this as the answer after some time, to see if there is another solution.